# Generic Function to Create Options

Tags: java, scala, generics, jvm

The function below is supposed to take a `value` of type `String` and return an `Option` that matches the type of the second argument of the function, e.g.

`toOption[Double]("10", classOf[Double])`

```
def toOption[A](value: String, classType: A): Option[A] = {
    classType match {
        case _: Int => {
            try {
                Some(value.trim().toInt)
            } catch {
                case e: NumberFormatException => None
            }
        }
        case _: Double => {
            try {
                Some(value.trim().toDouble)
            } catch {
                case e: NumberFormatException => None
            }
        }
        case _: java.sql.Timestamp => {
            try {
                Some(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(value.trim()))
            } catch {
                case e: NumberFormatException => None
            }
        }
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

However, as the function currently is, I get the errors below. How can/should I resolve these errors?

```
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: A
                       Some(value.trim().toInt)
                                         ^
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: A
                       Some(value.trim().toDouble)
                                         ^
<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.sql.Timestamp
 required: A
                       Some(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(value.trim()))
```

Comment: when you call it and you specify the [A] explicit do you have the same error?

Comment: @stsatlantis I can't call the function, error occurs on function creation in REPL.

Comment: btw the try{} catch exception can be replaced with Try{}.toOption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you have to cast it: `Some(value.trim.toInt).asInstanceOf[A]`. It does not know that A as `Int`.

Here is a better way:

```
 trait FromString[T] { 
   def convert(s: String): T
   def apply(s: String): Option[T] = Try(convert(s.trim)).toOption
 }

 implicit object IntFromString extends FromString[Int] {
   def convert(s: String) = s.toInt
 }
 implicit object DoubleFromString extends FromString[Double] {
   def convert(s: String) = s.toDouble
 } 
 // etc.
```

So, now, you can write:

```
def toOption[T : FromString](s: String): Option[T] = implicitly[FromString[T]](s)
```

Or, if you want to get a `None` back when there is no conversion defined:

```
def toOption[T](s: String)(implicit conv: FromString[T] = null) = Option(conv)
 .flatMap(_.apply(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting solves your issue because the compiler cannot relate the mapping with type you get from the pattern matching.

```
import scala.util.Try

def toOption[A](value: String, classType: A): Option[A] = {
classType match {
  case _: Int =>
    Try {
      value.trim().toInt.asInstanceOf[A]
    } toOption
  case _: Double =>
    Try {
      value.trim().toDouble.asInstanceOf[A]
    } toOption
  case _: java.sql.Timestamp =>
    Try {
      java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(value.trim()).asInstanceOf[A]
    } toOption
  case _ => Option.empty[A]
 }
}
```

Edit: @Dima's solution with the type class is more elegant